# how to change highlight color in list control in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

how to change highlight color in list control in mfc.
i havn't found any api in clistctrl.
 i have override NM_CUSTOMDRAW as descripbed in msdn
but when i clicked on any item on list it showing half blue color and half black color
why blue is coming ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to override [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774865(VS.85).aspx) handler. Check [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048(VS.80).aspx#customdraw_topic4).

Comment: thanks for the link.
i tried this but on clicking on list control items it is getting highlighted with blue..what would be the problem?

Comment: @Kirill V. Lyadvinsky is blue is default highlight color?

Comment: Default highlight color is defined by current Windows theme. In your case it is blue.

Comment: You can override it in the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` handler. Set `clrTextBk` field of `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW` structure when `nmcd.uItemState` is equal to `CDIS_FOCUS`.

Comment: @Kirill V. Lyadvinsky method you offered doesn`t work, if the item in the list has state "selected" highlight is painted using system color and clrTextBk is not taken into account. Also example you advised doesn`t relate to the question that was asked, because different technic should be used for changing highlight color. I faced with the same problem, and found the solution: on the predraw stage I change the state of the selected item to non selected and on after draw state I reverse changes, but this solution doesn`t satisfy my needs, because if item state is changed - application work bad.

Comment: @Kirill V. Lyadvinsky can you offer another solution? in which state of the item is not affected???

Comment: @spin_eight, the solution works for me, can't say why it doesn't for you without seeing your code. i suppose you need to ask your own question and supply it with a minimal sample which illustrates the problem.

Comment: I know I'm years late to this, but for anyone wondering, you need to get rid of the `CDIS_SELECTED` flag from the item state when handling `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` under `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` like this: `lplvcd->nmcd.uItemState &= ~CDIS_SELECTED;`. As far as I can tell, this will force windows to not draw the item as if it were selected, but it will still be selected as far as the control is concerned, i.e. through `CListCtrl::GetItemState`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to change the color of the selected item based on Kirill V. Lyadvinsky's answer.

My dialog class contains a `CTreeCtrl` member that uses the resource ID `IDC_TEST_DEF_TREE`.
The method `OnNMCustomdraw` sets the color of the selected item. The message handler is registered in the message map like this:

```
ON_NOTIFY(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, IDC_TEST_DEF_TREE, OnNMCustomdraw)
```

The method's implementation:

```
void CSelectTestDefinitionDlg::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lpLVCustomDraw = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
    switch (lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    case CDDS_SUBITEM:
        if (lpLVCustomDraw->nmcd.uItemState & CDIS_SELECTED)
        {
            // Your color definitions here:
            lpLVCustomDraw->clrText = RGB(255, 255, 255);
            lpLVCustomDraw->clrTextBk = RGB(0, 70, 60);
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    *pResult = 0;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    *pResult |= CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
}
```